# Error 'Parameter 'Identity.type' can not be None. ' while creating a Kusto cluster from Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-data-explorer

The command I'm using:

```sh
az kusto cluster create --location "brazilsouth" --name "adxrrs" --sku name="Dev(No SLA)_Standard_D11_v2" capacity=1 tier="Basic" --resource-group adx-rg
```

output:

```sh
Command group 'kusto' is experimental and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
Parameter 'Identity.type' can not be None.
```

I'm already logged in and have no idea what does **'Identity.type'** suppose to mean?

---

- My environment:

  - OS: Ubuntu 20.04 Focal
  - Azure-cli -v: 2.28.0

**--debug** output:

```sh
Command group 'kusto' is experimental and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
cli.azure.cli.core.commands.client_factory: Getting management service client client_type=KustoManagementClient
msrest.exceptions: Parameter 'Identity.type' can not be None.
cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/home/rrs/.azure/cliextensions/kusto/azext_kusto/generated/custom.py", line 85, in kusto_cluster_create
    parameters=parameters)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/util.py", line 646, in sdk_no_wait
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rrs/.azure/cliextensions/kusto/azext_kusto/vendored_sdks/kusto/operations/_clusters_operations.py", line 223, in begin_create_or_update
    **kwargs
  File "/home/rrs/.azure/cliextensions/kusto/azext_kusto/vendored_sdks/kusto/operations/_clusters_operations.py", line 151, in _create_or_update_initial
    body_content = self._serialize.body(parameters, 'Cluster')
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 628, in body
    raise errors[0]
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 250, in validate
    Serializer.validate(value, debug_name, **self._validation.get(attr_name, {}))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 730, in validate
    raise ValidationError("required", name, True)
msrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'Identity.type' can not be None.

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Parameter 'Identity.type' can not be None.
az_command_data_logger: Parameter 'Identity.type' can not be None.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x7fb72d698400>]
az_command_data_logger: exit code: 1
cli.__main__: Command ran in 0.255 seconds (init: 0.087, invoke: 0.168)
telemetry.save: Save telemetry record of length 3197 in cache
telemetry.check: Negative: The /home/rrs/.azure/telemetry.txt was modified at 2021-09-21 14:46:40.815964, which in less than 600.000000 s
```

Comment: Please run the command passing `--debug` to get more details of the error and share the relevant output.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara just added to the question body. Tks.

Comment: Yup, seems like a known issue. Feel free to accept your own answer so it helps others running into similar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a known issue reported at:

- [azure-cli #18827](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18827)

Adding the flag `--type=None` to the command made it works.